# Lookup giving wrong results in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am new in mongodb. I am facing issue while using lookup. I have two documents. **users** and **user_posts**

```
users collection
db.users.find({}).pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a7"),
"name" : "kunal",
"email" : "kunal@gmail.com",
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30ab"),
"name" : "Amit",
"email" : "amit@gmail.com",
}
```

Now i have other collection

```
user_posts collection
db.user_posts.find({}).pretty();
{
"_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a8"),
"user_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a7"),
"post_name" : "Test Post"
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a9"),
"user_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a7"),
"post_name" : "Test Post 2"
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30aa"),
"user_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a7"),
"post_name" : "Test Post 3"
}
```

Now if you see all user_posts belongs to kunal user_id (655c3285822c4a52150c30a7) but when i aggreate the data with lookup its returning me both users. See the below results

```
> db.user_posts.aggregate([{$lookup: {from: "users",localField: "id",foreignField: "user_id",as: "user_info"}}]).pretty();
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a8"),
          "user_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a7"),
          "post_name" : "Test Post",
          "updated_at" : ISODate("2023-11-21T04:31:01.232Z"),
          "created_at" : ISODate("2023-11-21T04:31:01.232Z"),
          "user_info" : [
            {
              "_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a7"),
              "name" : "kunal",
              "email" : "kunal@gmail.com",
            },
            {
              "_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30ab"),
              "name" : "Amit",
              "email" : "amit@gmail.com",
            }
          ]
        }
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a9"),
          "user_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a7"),
          "post_name" : "Test Post 2",
          "updated_at" : ISODate("2023-11-21T04:31:01.233Z"),
          "created_at" : ISODate("2023-11-21T04:31:01.233Z"),
          "user_info" : [
            {
              "_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a7"),
              "name" : "kunal",
              "email" : "kunal@gmail.com",
            },
            {
              "_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30ab"),
              "name" : "Amit",
              "email" : "amit@gmail.com",
            }
          ]
        }
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30aa"),
          "user_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a7"),
          "post_name" : "Test Post 3",
          "updated_at" : ISODate("2023-11-21T04:31:01.234Z"),
          "created_at" : ISODate("2023-11-21T04:31:01.234Z"),
          "user_info" : [
            {
              "_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a7"),
              "name" : "kunal",
              "email" : "kunal@gmail.com",
            },
            {
              "_id" : ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30ab"),
              "name" : "Amit",
              "email" : "amit@gmail.com",
            }
          ]
        }
```

Now if you see both users are coming in user_info object. It should come only kunal user as these posts belongs to that user only why other users also coming?.. What i am doing wrong in the query?

Comment: there is no id field in user_posts (localfield) and no user_id field in users (foreignField). do you mean like https://mongoplayground.net/p/CG2PrGoY5hp

Comment: Thank You so mcuh .. Can you give me one advice?

Comment: can we make relation using objectid? or numeric which one is good way?

Comment: Like mysql using numeric and mongodb using the (objectid)

Comment: Its your choice,study and apply which is more feasible.
As for me,i would choose relation with objectId because it consist lots of things.for example you can extract creation date from the ObjectId.which i use in many cases.

Comment: depends on the use case. both are possible. for example i have worked with collections that have a separate unique field  (using a uuid) apart from the auto generated _id

Comment: @cmgchess Thanks is there any performace issue to execute both cases ?? Suppose if i take uuid in users collection and user_posts uuid refernce as foreign  ?

Answer (score 0):

you could write a query as follows

```
db.users.aggregate([
{
    $match: { name: "kunal" }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "posts",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "user_id",
        as: "user_posts"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$user_posts"
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: "$user_posts._id",
        post_name: "$user_posts.post_name",
        user_id: "$user_posts.user_id"
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with localField and foreignField.

**foreignField:**

This is the field from the **target** documents.

So it should be "**_id**" as the target document is "**users**"

**localField:**

This is the field from the **input** documents.

So it should be "**user_id**" as the input document is "**user_posts**"

The modified code snippet:

```
 {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "user_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user_info"
    }
  }
```

The complete query will be:

```
  > db.user_posts.aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "user_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "user_info"
        }
      }
]).pretty();
```